# My activity crashes when making object of json

Tags: android, json, object

When ever i made a object of JSONObject my crashes
when ever i enter this line in my onPostExecute override fun
`val jsonObject=JSONObject(result)`
my activity damn crashes after starting the android emulator
my whole code is below

```
package shubham.lists.simpleapicalldemo

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.DataOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
import java.net.URL
import java.sql.Connection

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        CallAPILoginAsyncTask("SHUBHAM","123456").execute()
    }

    private inner class CallAPILoginAsyncTask(val username:String,val password:String): AsyncTask<Any, Void, String>() {
        private lateinit var customProgressDialog:Dialog

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            showProgressDialog()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?): String? {
            var result:String
            var connection:HttpURLConnection?=null
            try{                                        //this link is getting from the mocky.JSON
                val url=URL("https://run.mocky.io/v3/3fb2c711-55ea-4de3-aee4-2d7c6848c9d3")
                connection=url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.doInput=true
                connection.doOutput=true
                connection.instanceFollowRedirects=false
                connection.requestMethod="POST"
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json")
                connection.setRequestProperty("charset","utf-8")
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json")
                connection.useCaches=false
                val writeDataOutputStream= DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
                val jsonRequest=JSONObject()
                jsonRequest.put("username",username)
                jsonRequest.put("password",password)
                writeDataOutputStream.writeBytes(jsonRequest.toString())
                writeDataOutputStream.flush()
                writeDataOutputStream.close()
                val httpResult:Int=connection.responseCode
                if(httpResult==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    val inputStream=connection.inputStream
                    val reader=BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                    val stringBuilder=StringBuilder()
                    var line:String?
                    try {
                        while(reader.readLine().also { line=it }!=null){
                            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n")
                        }
                    } catch (e:IOException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    finally {
                        try{
                            inputStream.close()
                        } catch (e:IOException){
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
                    result=stringBuilder.toString()
                }
                else{
                    result=connection.responseMessage
                }
            }
            catch (e:SocketTimeoutException){
                result="Connection timed out"
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                result="Error "+ e.message
            }
            finally {
                connection?.disconnect()
            }
            return result
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            cancelProgressDialog()
            Log.i("JSON RESPONSE RESULT","$result")
            val jsonObject=JSONObject(result)          //deconstructing json object
            /*val message=jsonObject.optString("message")
            Log.i("message",message)
            val user_id=jsonObject.optInt("USER_ID")
            Log.i("user_id","$user_id")
            val profiledetails=jsonObject.optJSONObject("profile_details") //deconstructing json object inside json object
            val is_profile_completed= profiledetails?.optString("IS_PROFILE_COMPLETED")
            Log.i("is_profile_completed","$is_profile_completed")
            val dataList=jsonObject.optJSONArray("data-list")
            val dataListArray=jsonObject.optJSONArray()
            jsonObject=JSONObject(result)
            Log.i(“Data list size”,”${datalistArray.size()}”)
            for(item in 0 until datalistArray.length()){
            Log.i(“value $item”,”${datalistArray[item]}”)
            Val dataItemObject:JSONObject=datalistArray[item] as JSONObject
            val id=dataitemObject.optInt(“id”)
            Log.i(“ID”,$”id”)
            val value=dataitemObject.optString(“value”)
            Log.i(“value”,$”value”)
            */
        }

        private fun showProgressDialog(){
            customProgressDialog=Dialog(this@MainActivity)
            customProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_progress)
            customProgressDialog.show()
        }
        private fun cancelProgressDialog(){
            customProgressDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as well.

Comment: I can't tell the problem before reading stack trace, but I don't understand why don't you use Retrofit or Fast Android Networking  or etc?